# C programming Arrays with Functions

Tags: c, arrays

My program is suppose to read the Numbers text file which is where I have listed my numbers and store them into an array then display in 5 columns. My problem is that it wont display the array at all. Im not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ELEMENTS 100

void fillArray(FILE *, double [], double *);
void printArray(double [], double); 
double findMIN(double [], double);
double findMAX(double [], double);

int main()
{
    FILE *doublefp;
    double values[ELEMENTS];
    double elements;
    int status;

    status = fopen_s(&doublefp, "Numbers.txt", "r");
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file Numbers.txt\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(99);
    }

    fillArray(doublefp, values, &elements);
    printArray(values, elements);


    printf("The minimum value is %d\n", findMIN(values, elements));

    printf("The maximum value is %d\n", findMAX(values, elements));

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

double findMIN(double nums[], double element)
{
    int i;
    double min = nums[0];

    for (i = 1; i < element; i++)
    if (min > nums[i])
      min = nums[i];

  return (min);
}

double findMAX(double nums[], double element)
{
    int i;
    double max = nums[0];

    for (i = 1; i < element; i++)
    if (max < nums[i])
      max = nums[i];

  return (max);

}

void fillArray (FILE *fp, double nums[], int *count)
{
    double number;

    printf("Enter up to %d integers press the F6 key to end input. \n", ELEMENTS);
    *count = 0;
    while (fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &nums[*count]) != EOF)
    {
        (*count)++;
    }

}

void printArray (double nums[], double elements)
{
    int count;

    printf("Values in array:\n");
    for (count = 0; count < elements; count++)
    {
        printf("%5d ",nums[count]);
        if ((count+1)% 10 == 0)
           printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");printf("\n");


}
```

My numbers are in a text file listed like this:
23.53 
56.8 
12.1
677.23 
122.09 
788.18 
123.25 
65.12
98.18
622.27 
366.34 
433.45 
844.56 
244.67 
544.78 
290.10 
189.28 
522.17 
321.33
178.76

Comment: The `%d` conversion operates on integers. Try using `%f` for `double`s instead. You'll also want the file to contain one value per line.

Comment: Turn on all the warnings in your complier, fix them and then ask again.

Comment: `fillArray()` isn't even defined in the same way that it's declared, this code shouldn't even compile, let alone compile without warnings.

Comment: I had to keep changing them around so my pointers would work and I guess my warnings wasn't on either. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1) Your "printf()" format statement should use "%d" to print integers, and "%lf" to print doubles.  You're not doing this consistently.

2) You're better off using an "int" for "counting numbers", instead of double.  Unfortunately, you're not doing this consistently, either.

SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ELEMENTS 100

void fillArray(FILE * fp, double values [], int * count);
void printArray(double values[] int count); 
double findMIN(double values[], int count);
double findMAX(double values[], int count);

int main()
{
    FILE *doublefp;
    double values[ELEMENTS];
    int elements;
    int status;

    status = fopen_s(&doublefp, "Numbers.txt", "r");
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file Numbers.txt\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(99);
    }

    fillArray(doublefp, values, &elements);
    printArray(values, elements);


    printf("The minimum value is %f\n", findMIN(values, elements));
    printf("The maximum value is %f\n", findMAX(values, elements));

    system ("PAUSE");
   ...   

double findMIN(double nums[], int count)
   ...

void fillArray (FILE *fp, double nums[], int *count)
{
    printf("Enter up to %d integers press the F6 key to end input. \n", ELEMENTS);
    *count = 0;
    while (fscanf_s(fp, "%f", &nums[*count]) != EOF)
    {
        (*count)++;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: 1 more thing. Im trying to format the decimals so it wont have all the zeros after that. I tried %8.2f but it gives me an error this time. EDIT: Nevermind. I got it c:

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `double elements;` needs to be `int elements`

Here `&elements` is a `double *`, the function `fillArray` expects an `int *`

```
fillArray(doublefp, values, &elements);
```

**Did you turn the warnings on in your compiler?**

Also, in `printArray`, `elements` is defined as a `double` when it should be an `int`.

Same with `findMax` and `findMin`.

And `printf("%5d ",nums[count]);` should be `printf("%lf ",nums[count]);`

**Turn on all the warnings in your complier, fix them and then ask again if it doesn't work.**

Comment: I saw the warnings in the ouput when building. I fix them all and now it works. Thank you!